# PHP/MySQL registeration page does nothing

Tags: php, mysql

all. I have a registration page that, well, registers users' inputted data into the MySQL database and in return can login. Simple.

But the code I use seems to not do anything at all. When I entered generic information in fields, the database has no new tables or information. (The table I'm trying to apply info to is called 'users'.) In fact, none of the checks appear either (such as you entered no password etc.)

You can view the full code [here](http://pastebin.com/wSB48ezF). The database info I'm connecting to goes as follows:
Database: mk7
Username: root
Password:
Host: localhost
Table to apply: users

Also, I heard that the method I am using is prone to SQL Injection and no password hashing/salting. If someone could help me improve/add this to my code, I will greatly appreciate it. I am a bit of a novice in writing PHP, but I have nearly complete understanding of what's going on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change

```
switch($act) to switch($_REQUEST['act'])
```

and tell us whats happens.  Yes the code is messy and prone to alot of attacks, not just sql injection.  If you want some secure code, DM me.

Comment: That worked, thank you. And I have no idea why I got a -3 rep for that question, I am just a beginner. This code I'm using will go on a public server, so I would be grateful for some secure code. And what is a "DM"?